# Can't upload file by "input" in php

Tags: php, file, upload

it returning "not working" but i made it with php documentation 
index.php :

```
<form action="odbierz.php" method="POST" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="plik"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit"/> <br/>
</form>
```

odbierz.php

```
<?php

$dir = '/foto/';
$plik = $dir.basename($_FILES['plik']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name'],$plik)){
    echo "uploaded";
} else {
    echo "not working \n";
}
echo "<img src='".$plik."'>";

?>
```

Comment: Have you checked `$plik` value? Do you have enough privileges to write into `foto` folder?

Comment: how can i change or check privileges of this folder?

Comment: Use **try** & **catch** to get the exact error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **remove** the first **`/`** from `"/foto/"`. Or if your php file is not in same folder where foto folder is, then use **`../`** like **`../foto/`** if foto is outside the folder where php file exsits.

```
<?php

   $dir = 'foto/';

   if( isset ($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name'] )) { 

      $plik = $dir.basename($_FILES['plik']['name']);


      if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['plik']['tmp_name'],$plik)){
         echo "uploaded";
      } 
      else {
         echo "not working \n";
      }
      echo "<img src='".$plik."'>";
   }       
?>
```